# nodejs ask python-minimal that no longer use on python2

Tags: python, node.js, installation, version

i use linux
nodejs had no problem untill i upgraded my system (sudo apt upgrade)
now when i try to install nodejs it say python-minimal mot installed
then i knew that it casue of updating python from python2.7.17 to python2.7.18 and python minimal is no longer require ,but now i cant install nodejs cause it ask for python-minimal

can any one help me

the problem is when i want to install nodejs 15 or 14
but when i install nodejs 12 or lower it have no problem

this is what it say after i write (sudo apt install nodejs)

```
sudo apt upgrade nodejs
[sudo] password for julian: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnode72 : Conflicts: nodejs-legacy
 nodejs : Depends: python-minimal but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
sudo apt remove libnode72:amd64
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue today after going from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 and there are a lot of [old Ask Ubuntu questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222566/not-able-to-install-nodejs-in-ubuntu-command-line) surrounding this and [Github questions](https://github.com/beefproject/beef/issues/2016) where for one reason or another various apps (Node included) rely on core Python functions that are leveraged from the python-minimal library.

For better or worse it also doesn't seem to care if Python is installed or not in it's entirety. It wants the minimal package specifically.

The thing is [all the python-minimal repositories are marked OldStable](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=python-minimal) (about [OldStable](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianOldStable) if you want to know)and rely on [Python 2 which has been sunset.](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)

It seems if you haven't upgraded your OS in a while there is something hanging out in the package manager that will tell you that node needs python minimal to be run or installed but this is not the case as is evident by the lack of package support.

The solution I found was after upgrade to [simply rerun the installation for Node based on the package manager instructions for your operating system](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/). In my case it was specifically [Dedbian and Ubuntu based distributions.](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md)